# Problem with notification scheduling in WEB Applications

Tags: php, cron, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, scheduled-tasks, at-job

## Context

I'm currently implementing a feature to schedule notifications for a specific period through a web form using PHP and Firebase.

To send the notification I use Firebase and it sends notifications to Android/Ios.

To schedule the notification I use the `AT` linux service, as it seems to suit better than `cron`, as `cron` runs at certain frequencies and `AT` does not, it runs at a specific time.

man page about the AT: [man page AT](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at)

## Sample code

```
/usr/bin/php `send_notification.php` | at 2021-07-11 15:40
```

This will create a file on linux that will run in the period 2021-07-11 15:40 only once.

## Problems

The `AT` service, like `CRON`, creates files inside a directory on the operating system that represent the jobs.

1 - If a machine on AWS is scaled, jobs would likely be duplicated and consequently send notifications more than once. (Note: I don't know much about machine scaling, but I believe it should happen)

2 - And if the machine is in downtime due to the inclusion of some functionality or something like that, I believe that the way it is currently the job would not be executed.

3 - Another problem, but not the main one, would be if I was using a docker container. As Ubuntu + PHP are inside the container, the job files would probably be lost if I restarted the container, so in this case I believe that a solution would be to use volume, but that would not be my problem now, as currently the application uses only one machine on AWS EB with the PHP image.

## Doubts

- Is there any solution I can apply to solve this duplicate job problem using PHP?
- Is the approach using `AT` the most suitable? I see a lot of people talking to use `CRON`, but CRON will run the job several times and for me that's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a place where scheduled and finished notifications will be persisted, independently on what you are using, cron or at.

If I had such a task, I would stay with a solution like this: run special script, "scheduler.php" each 1 (or more, e.g. 5) mins by cron, which will check some log file(or remote database in case of several machines) and look if there are any new lines. If new line present and it contains timestamp in the past and status "sceduled", than script will lock it and run your "sender.php". After that it will mark the line as "done". Each line in a storage should contain a timestamp to run and one of three statuses "scheduled", "running" and "done".

With such approach you could plan new notifications by adding a line with needed time and status "scheduled" to the storage. Note, that there can be a little delay between scheduled time and actual notification depending on the cron interval, but I suppose it is not critical.

This will allow you to run any number of crons on different machines and guarantee that each job will be done once.

Important: if you will adopt this scheme, be sure that your scheduler.php reads and updates a storage in a single atomic operation, to prevent race conditions between several crons. File locks, or "select for update" will do.

Comment: Let me see if I understand, based on your answer, the storage lines [Database, Log file] that would have the following schema (timestamp, status) would be an analogy to crontab?

Example:

2021-07-12 19:43 | done
2021-07-12 20:54 | running
2021-07-12 20:56 | scheduled

But how will this work for a `sender.php` that is dynamic?

The notification sending has some parameters that vary like `topic`, `title`, `message`, ...

I currently pass this through command parameters and capturing in script.php using `getopt`

exemplo: 
`command.php --title="title xxx" --message="message xxxx"`

Comment: I mean the format like `2021-07-14 12:30:00,scheduled`, where first column is time to run and second - status. But if you need to provide your sender.php with some params, you can change the format and add other columns.

Comment: You can alternatively use simpler solution: modify your sender.php to check external log before doing actual job. Put a unique key of job, (e.g. hash of concatenated patameters and current time) to the storage, and do not do job if such key exists. Then contine running script manually with AT, as you do.

Comment: I didn't quite understand why "check a hash with parameters + timestamp concatenated". Why should I do this check before running the job with AT?

Comment: And about the lock file issue, I believe it would not work when a machine scales, because I believe the lockfile blocks access to processes on the same machine, but when you scale a machine on aws or any other Cloud, it kind of replicates the machine, so it blocks it would not work very well.

Comment: Hash is a key signalizing that such a job is already running. Each job should check if the key exists, and if not - insert it and do actual work. This will guarantee that work is not done more than once.

Comment: Yes, you are right, local files will not do in case of several machines. In this case you need some external database with support of atomic transactions. In case of Mysql "select for update" will work fine.

Comment: Also there is a simpler alternative to "select for update": set unique index on field, and just try to insert new key when script is running. Wrap this lines in try-catch and if there is and exception with mysql code 2300 ("Duplicate entry") - the key already exists. This technique guarantees atomicity too.